# Raspberry Pi 3B+ No Boot (Hardware Failure?)

Tags: raspbian, boot, hardware, pi-3b+, boot-issues

Between two identical out of the box RasPi's 3B+ (same supplier and model), one of them boots flawlessly with SD Card running 2019-04-08-raspbian-stretch but the other refuses too with all the same Hardware plugged in (HDMI cord, charger, usb mouse and Keyboard). When the nonbooting raspi is plugged in it only flashes ist green light 4 times and has a solid red light. Though I have gotten a low voltage warning on the working one (offical supply is otw) would that affect this one differently? Is there someway to fix the nonbooting one or is it completly dead?
EDIT: Though it may be an SD Card Slot issue shouldn't it be able to boot from USB regardless?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [I can't boot my Pi! (4 flashing green Lights)](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/15773/i-cant-boot-my-pi-4-flashing-green-lights). Please also refer to [The Boot Problems Sticky](https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?f=28&t=58151).

Comment: I wouldnt think so as the Card clearly works it seems to be a Problem with the PI itself which isnt mentioned there. And according to the sticky this Situation would categoriye the non-boot one as bad but i am wondering what is bad and is it fixable? @Ingo

Comment: But the guide says "4-flashes may point to a defective SD-card holder, if one or more of the data contacts is intermittent it can lead to this problem."

Comment: Welcome and good luck.

Comment: @tlfong01 shouldnt it be able to boot from USB in spite of that. I just burned (and tested) on my working pi perfectly but on the 'broken' pi it is respondiong in the same way by blinking.

Comment: Ah, I know too little about booting from USB to get around the possibly broken SD card holder problem.  But I am interested to know if you have configured both good and bad Rpi to boot from USB?

Comment: I have gotten the good one to boot from both SD and USB but neither on the broken

Comment: Ah, let me see.  If good Rpi can boot from both SD card holder and USB socket, but bad Rpi cannot do either.  This seems to conclude that the problem is not caused by the SD card holder.  I know too little to suggest anything now.  Sorry about that.